# Execute two functions at onClick with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I currently have this table, where when the user clicks the button it toogles the "editForm" state, but I also want to change the idColab state when the user clicks the button, how can I accomplish that?

obs: The ID is passed as a parameter.

```
const [editForm, setEditForm] = useState(false)
const [idColab, setIdColab] = useState("")


const exibirForm = () => {
        setEditForm(!editForm)
}

const setIdColab = (id) => {
        idColab = id
}
```

The ID comes from this mapping:

```
const renderTable = () => {
        return data.map((colaborador, idx) => {
            const {id, nome, matricula, funcao, tipo_acesso, cpf} = colaborador

            return (
                <tr>
                    <td className='data-cell'>{nome}</td>
                    <td className='data-cell'>{matricula}</td>
                    <td className='data-cell'>{newFuncao}</td>
                    <td className='data-cell'>{newAcesso}</td>
                    <td className='data-cell'>{cpf}</td>
                    <td className='data-cell'>{id}</td>
                    <td className='btn-cell'><input className="edit-btn" type="submit" value="Editar" onClick={exibirForm(id)} /></td>
                </tr>
            ) 
        })
    }
```

Comment: You create a third function that calls the other two and use that as the onclick

Comment: The ID is passed as a parameter from where?

Comment: It comes from a mapping, I return it inside the table as table cells, but I want to pass it as a parameter aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 1

By adding the code within the called function:

```
const exibirForm = () => {
  setEditForm(!editForm)
  setInput({ idColab: "1234"  });
}
```

#### Option 2

By creating a function that calls more functions

```
const masterFunction = () => {
  function1();
  function2();
  // ... more functions ...
}
```

Or even more compact:

```
<input onClick={() => { function1(); function2(); }} />
```

Comment: And how am I supposed to pass the ID as a parameter? Because when I do that, react returns me an error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop". I'm trying to pass it like this:

onClick={exibirForm(id)

Comment: @ThiagoSalgado `onClick={exibirForm(id)} `This doesn't pass a function in to onClick, it calls exibirForm right away and passes the *return value* in. Do this instead: `onClick={() => exibirForm(id)}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicholasTower! It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent function that calls both functions in it and pass the parent function to your event listener .